# Appending image url from an object after being filtered with $.jquery.grep

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

So I am trying to use jquery to grep to create a filter I can use to populate images on certain pages.

I managed to get it to filter but when I try to console log the result is shows up as undefined. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var heroImage = [{}];

  var itemList = [{
      "itemImage ": "../images/trend/greenpants.jpg",
      "itemName": "Green Pants",
      "itemType": "pants",
      "itemClass": "trend",
      "itemDep": "male"
    },
    {
      "itemImage ": "../images/trend/greenpants.jpg",
      "itemName": "Snow Coat",
      "itemType": "coat",
      "itemClass": "collection",
      "itemDep": "female"
    },
    {
      "itemImage ": "../images/trend/greenpants.jpg",
      "itemName": "Orange Mittens",
      "itemType": "accessories",
      "itemClass": "trend"
    },
    {
      "itemImage ": "../images/trend/greenpants.jpg",
      "itemName": "White Blazer",
      "itemType": "shirt",
      "itemClass": "collection",
      "itemDep": "male"
    },
    {
      "itemImage ": "../images/trend/greenpants.jpg",
      "itemName": "Brown Shirt",
      "itemType": "shirt",
      "itemClass": "trend",
      "itemDep": "female"
    }

  ];

  /*$("div").text(JSON.stringify(itemList));*/

  var itemAarray = jQuery.grep(itemList, function(x, i) {
    return (x.itemDep === "male");
  }, false);

  console.log(itemAarray.itemName);

  var image = $('<img/>').attr('src', itemAarray.itemImage);

  $(".gallery").append(image);
  /*text(JSON.stringify(itemAarray))*/


});
```

Comment: `$.grep()` returns a new array, not a single object....try `console.log(itemAarray[0].itemName);`

Comment: Gave console.log(itemAarray[0].itemImage) a shot and it still pulls up undefined :( Does work with item name though.

Comment: Strange you can access one property but not another if I understand correctly.

Comment: Hmm well it looks like when you console.log(itemAarray[0) it pulls up the whole array of the first result. I don't want to use a for loop to to loop and search because I need it to filter based on multiple properties.

Comment: If you are just looking for first item match use `Array#find()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: That didn't seem to help too much, I went back and did it with a for loop and got close. One of the urls was undefined but the second showed up.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are curious, I did solve this!

I decided .grep wouldn't work and went with a for loop instead.

That seemed to solve my issue

```
 for (var i = 0, len = itemList.length; i < len; i++)

      {

        if (itemList[i].itemDep === "male")

        {

          var stock = $('<img/>').attr('src', itemList[i].itemImage);

          $(".gallery").append(stock);

          console.log(itemList[i].itemImage); // Return as soon as the 
          object is found

        }

      }
```